# Session not updated in template?

Tags: django, session

i implement a shopping cart which stores the item ids in a list in a session. my add method looks like this

```
def add_to_cart(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'cart' not in request.session:
      request.session['cart'] = []
    if not request.POST['item-id'] in request.session['cart']:
      request.session['cart'].append(request.POST['item-id'])

    return HttpResponse('true')
```

by printing the session in the add method, i get the correct number of elements. but when reloading the view, where i try to read the list stored in the session, i only get a list with one single element in it. my view looks like this

```
def cart(request):
  cart_items = request.session['cart']
  print len(cart_items)
  return render(request, 'checkout/cart.html', ({ 'items': cart_items }))
```

in the template i just want to print the list like this:

```
{% load cart_helpers %}

{% block content %}
<div class="cart">
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>Warenkorb</h2>
    <table class="listing">
      {{ items }}
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

no matter what i do, the list in my cart-session has just one item...

any advice? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view, you need to set `request.session.modified = True` to indicate that you have modified the session object.
So update your view to

```
def add_to_cart(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'cart' not in request.session:
      request.session['cart'] = []
    if not request.POST['item-id'] in request.session['cart']:
      request.session['cart'].append(request.POST['item-id'])

      request.session.modified = True  #set modified state

    return HttpResponse('true')
```

This is required because

```
request.session['cart'].append(request.POST['item-id'])
```

does not modify `request.session` but modifies `request.session['cart']`, in such cases django does not know about the modified session and does not save it.

Refer [When sessions are saved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved)